# Do even Kansai women use the ～ん negative?

Tags: dialects, kansai-ben, gender

As in 分からん and ならん. In Standard (?) speech, I'm fairly certain it's masculine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes we do! :D

Here in Kyoto we use both わからん and わからへん. I think Osakan women rather use わからん. As for ならん, I think it's あかん in Kansai. Yes, we Kansai women use it daily, too.

We talk like:

> あかんって。(=だめだって。)
>   あかんやん。
>   あかんやろ。 (=だめだろう。)
>   知らん。(=知らない。)
>   知らんで。(=知らないよ。)
>   知らんわ。
>   知らんし。
>   あらへん。(=ない。)
>   あらへんで。(=ないよ。)
>   いらんわ～。(=要らないわ～。)
>   ありえへん。(=ありえない。)
>   こうてへん。(=買ってない。)
>   持ってへん。(=持ってない。)
>   いかへん？(Kyoto) / いけへん？(Osaka)(=行かない？)
>   いけへん。(Kyoto) / いかれへん。(Osaka)(=行けない。)
>   なあ、今からこーへん？(=ねえ、今から来ない？)
>   etc. etc...

Comment: ホンマもんの回答には勝たれへん！

Comment: Just out of curiosity, Is that usage of "ん" restricted to Kansai area? I recall to have heard something like "いかんとです (=だめなのです)” in Kyushu.

Comment: 九州や中国地方(広島とか岡山とか)の人も使う気がします。