What is the meaning of わかるやろ
I heard on the radio a host said わかるやろ. At first I thought that I misheard what was said and it was わかるだろ, but google search for わかるやろ produced quite a few hits.
What are possible meanings of this expression?

Does this help? https://jisho.org/word/%E3%82%84%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86

Thanks, I thought it was a set expression, like くそやろう, meaning "know-it-all asshole". It did not come to my mind to lookup やろう separately. Though I still can't find an authoritative source that it is Kanseiben.

Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55061/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/102200/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/25769/9831

Just as や is used in Kansai where だ is used in Tokyo, Kansai people also say やろう・やろ rather than だろう・だろ

It was heard on Fukuoka FM. They avoid using dialects. I don't hear Hakataben on the radio here either.

Goo-Dictionary has no reference to Kansaiben in its entry: https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%82%84%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86/#jn-223462
